# Authenticity of the narration that says that every man will get two women of this world in Jannah?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, source-identification, authenticity, reference-request

I want to know the authenticity of the narration that says that every man will get two women of this world in Jannah.

The narration is the following:-

Abu Hurayra narrated

Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) said, “Every man in heaven will go to 72 of the creatures of Allah (houris) and 2 of the women of mankind, these two women are superior to the creatures of Allah (houris) with their worshipping (good deeds) they had performed in this world.” [Bayhaqi, al-Bas wa’n-Nushur; Tabari, Tafsir; Abu Yala, Ibn Hajar,Fathu’l-Baari, Tabarani and others]

Ibn Hajr stated:-

Abu Huraira used this Hadith as a proof to maintain that women will outnumber men in Jannah. (Fath Al-Bari 10/30)

Ibn Kathir stated:-

The meaning hereby is, these two are from the daughters of Adam (i.e. women of this world) and with them are wide-eyed maidens as Allah the Almighty wishes.” (Siffah al-Jannah p.132 pub. Mo’assas al-Kutab al-Thaqafiyyah, Beirut 1993)

**The main question is: Where can I find this Hadith of Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) and what is the authenticity of this narration? Is this Abu Hurayra's own interpretation or the actual Hadith of the Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam)?**

Comment: Please avoid using irrelevant tags and try using rather relevant ones (read the tag info if available and feel free to edit, write one). I've edited your post accordingly. As to where you can find your quotes actually tell you references, therefore I'm confused on what you are exactly looking for.

Comment: I never knew "Source-identification" and "reference-request" tags even existed. My question was about hadith, so I used these tags. As I mentioned above, this Hadith is said to be in Tabari's tafsir, Ibn Hajr's Fath-ul-Bari, and other sources I mentioned. But I do not knwo where I can find this narration. or hadith